# Global variables in BaseHttpServer class

Tags: python, basehttpserver

I am using the method 'do_GET' of class BaseHttpServer.

I want to do is that successive calls to this method have access to the same shared variable

If I send the first command 0 then 1, I can not access the same variable

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from threading import Thread

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        #Some code
        if comand == 0:
             self.task()
        elif comand = 1:            
            #AttributeError: myHandler instance has no attribute 'var'
            temp = self.var 
        return

    def task(self):
       #Ok no exception 
       self.var = 0

#Main
server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), myHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: where does command come from?

Comment: comand = self.path[2]

Comment: Check this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444395/basehttprequesthandler-with-custom-instance/30288641#30288641

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem creating a [static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python), and using in static class global variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, myVariable, *args, **kwargs):
        self.myVariable = myVariable
        super(myHandler, self).__init__()
```

### #

```
server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), lambda *args, **kwargs : \
    myHandler(myVariable, *args, **kwargs))
```

Comment: TypeError: <lambda>() takes no arguments (3 given)                 File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)