# How to access RequestHandlerClass for HTTPServer in Python once it is set?

Tags: python, httpserver, basehttpserver

I have a custom `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler` that can (partially) be seen below. It has a special method that allows me to assign a reply generator - a class that takes some data in (for example the values of some of the parameters in a GET request) and generates an XML reply that can then be sent back to the client as a reply to the request:

```
class CustomHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  # implementation
  # ...

  def set_reply_generator(self, generator):
    self.generator = generator

  def do_GET(self):
    # process GET request
    # ...
    # and generate reply using generator
    reply = self.generator.generate(...) # ... are some parameters that were in the GET request
    # Encode
    reply = reply.encode()
    # set headers
    self.__set_headers__(data_type='application/xml', data=reply)
    # and send away
    self.wfile.write(reply)
    self.wfile.write('\n'.encode())
```

I pass this handler to the `BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer`:

```
def run(addr='127.0.0.1', port=8080):
  server_addr = (addr, port)
  server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_addr)
  server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.server_forever)
  server_thread.start()
```

Since the constructor of `BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer` expects a class and not an instance to be passed as the `RequestHandlerClass` argument I cannot just create an instance of my handler, call `set_reply_generator()` and then pass it on. Even if that worked I would still want to be able to access the handler later on (for example if through a POST request the reply generator for the GET requests is changed) and for that I need to know how to retrieve the instance that the server is using.

I've looked [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html) but I was unable to find it (perhaps missed it). I have the bad feeling that it is private (aka `__...__`).

All I was able to find out so far is that the class of the handler that the server uses can be retrieved through the `RequestHandlerClass` member, which however is not the same as retrieving an instance of the handler that will allow me to call the `set_reply_generator(...)`.

In addition I tried to actually create an instance of the custom handler but then I landed in a chicken-and-egg issue:

- the constructor of the handler requires you to pass the instance of the server
- the server requires you to pass the handler

This is sort of an indirect proof that the `HTTPServer`'s constructor is the one, that is responsible for instantiating the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18445168/1559401). No need to directly access the handler but rather create a static class member that can be access without an instance but still be processed when the handler wants to use it.