# How to pass parameter to GET-handler method of BaseHTTPRequestHandler class in Python

Tags: python, get, parameter-passing, httpserver, basehttprequesthandler

I have a HTTP server in Python created with

```
    from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
    import bson.json_util
    import json
    server = HTTPServer((ip, port), GetHandler)
    print ('Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop')
    server.serve_forever()
```

where `GetHandler`

```
class GetHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        json_string = json.dumps({"message" : "Hello"}, default=bson.json_util.default)+"\n"
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json_string.encode())#encoding='UTF-8'
        return
```

Suppose I want to pass a variable to the method `do_GET` of the class `GetHandler` from the line `server = HTTPServer((ip, port), GetHandler)`: how can I do that?

**EDIT**

Just as example suppose that I have a string `my_str` defined before the line `server = HTTPServer((ip, port), GetHandler)` and I want to use this string as response message.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my previous answer. I noticed that I did not really answer the question from your post. I have now edited with something that - I think - answers the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BaseHTTPRequestHandler with custom instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444395/basehttprequesthandler-with-custom-instance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python you can actually create classes inside functions. These classes will then have access the the function's locals via a closure.

The following code defines the function `make_handler` which, when called defines a new "handler" class with the value in `myvariable` available inside the whole class:

```
import json
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer


def make_handler(myvariable):

    class GetHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def _set_headers(self):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
            self.end_headers()

        def do_GET(self):
            self._set_headers()
            self.wfile.write(myvariable.encode('utf8'))
            return

    return GetHandler

server = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 50002), make_handler('my_str'))
print ('Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop')
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: How would you feel about subclassing `GetHandler` and using `super`?

Comment: It depends on what OP would like to achieve. When using subclassing you must define a new class for every possible input string. If that string value is very dynamic (f. ex. from user- or external-input), this is not feasible. If the values are however well-defined at the time the program is written, I would prefer subclassing, as it is easier to understand.